# Is it possible to harvest messages from other peoples discord servers?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Can I use the discord API in python to harvest messages from a server (not my own server)? Assuming you have an invite link.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would be possible. If you look under the *TextChannel* section of the *Discord Models* section of the [discord.py API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#), there is the `TextChannel` [history()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history) method. This can be used to parse all the messages in a channel. If the `limit` argument of the method is set to `None`, then all the messages in the channel will be returned.

Since you say that the bot already has an invite, that implies they have access to a good part of the server. The method I mentioned requires the following permissions for your bot:

- See Text Channels
- Read Message History

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your using a discord bot, you need them to invite your bot to their server.

Other than that you could theoretically listen with a bot on your own account but that would be against the discord TOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through a discord bot. Given that bots respond to events that fire within servers they reside in, you can listen in to incoming messages.

An example of such event can be found in [discord-py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message).